# php Explode on an Exact Word

Tags: php, regex, explode

Is it possible to have php explode work on an exact word? For example, I wish to split the string:

```
London Luton to Paris
```

However, php explode will find the first occurrence of 'to' which is in 'Luton'. This string is also possible:

```
Paris to London Luton
```

Which will correctly explode as the 'to' appears first.

Ideally, I wish for the explode to be case insensitive which I believe explode currently is. I figure however that RegEx is probably a better way to go here.

Comment: "I figure however that RegEx is probably a better way to go here." correct

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from including the spaces before and after `to` in the explode function ? Like `explode(' to ',$string)`.

Comment: Even to add on frz3993 comment: you can always concat a space before and after and explode on ' to '

Comment: But if you want case insensitivity better go the regex way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simple solution with `preg_split`:

```
$words = preg_split("/\bto\b/iu", "London Luton to Paris");
var_dump($words);

// the output:
array (size=2)
    0 => string 'London Luton ' (length=13)
    1 => string ' Paris' (length=6)
```

Comment: Just an alternative with inline modifiers: [`~(?i)\bto\b(?i-)`](https://regex101.com/r/wI3lR4/1) - nevertheless +1 :-)

Comment: @Jan, yes, in more complex cases inline modifiers can give a good  flexibility

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explode using `'to'` as separator then you can use the string `' to '` instead (it's `to` with one space on each side). This way only when `to` is a complete word it is treated as a separator, the `to` combination of letters from a larger word does not match.

However, if you need it to be case insensitive, a `regex` could be a better solution.

```
preg_split('/\bto\b/i', 'London Luton to Paris');
```

splits the string using `to` as the separator but only if it is a complete word (the `\b` that surround it match only word boundaries).

The `i` modifier tells the `regex` engine to ignore the case.

The spaces right near the `to` separator will be returned in the pieces you get. You can either `trim()` all the resulted strings

```
array_map('trim', preg_split('/\bto\b/i', 'Paris to London Luton');
```

or you can add them to the `regex`:

```
preg_split('/\s*\bto\b\s*/i', 'Paris to London Luton');
```

The `\s*` part matches a space character (`\s`) zero or more times (`*`). This way the word `to` is identified as a delimiter even if it appears as the first or the last word in the string, together with the spaces that surround it.