# PHP get first number

Tags: php

how can I get the first number from the function? I need to check how many numbers are there?

```php
$numbers = "1, 2, 3";
```

So my output needs to be like `1 is the first number, 3 numbers`

Comment: You got no function. You got an string. If you have a string, use explode on it to get the numbers. A tipp read the PHP documention => https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php Explode on an Exact Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138829/php-explode-on-an-exact-word)

Answer (score 2):

You may try with the next example. Use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the text:

```
<?php
$numbers = "1, 2, 3";
$array = explode(', ', $numbers);

echo $array[0]." is the first number, ".count($array)." numbers";
?>
```

Output:

```
1 is the first number, 3 numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot easier if you used an array instead of a string:

```
$numbers = array (8, 32, 83);
echo $numbers[0]." is first number, ";
echo count($numbers)." numbers";
```